# C# - How to calculate the current day-of-year?

Tags: c#, datetime

Today is `5.27.2010` - this means it is day 147 of this year.

How do I calculate that today is 147 based on the current date?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There's a `DateTime` property named just that: [DayOfYear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofyear.aspx)

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.DayOfYear);
```

Or for any date:

```
var d = new DateTime(2010, 5, 30);
Console.WriteLine(d.DayOfYear);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that in a leap year, days after Feb. 29 will have a `DayOfYear` one higher than in non-leap years.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, it's pretty easy:

```
int dayOfYear = DateTime.Today.DayOfYear;
```

Answer (score 5):

C#'s `DateTime` class has a method called `DayOfYear()` that you could use.

Answer (score 3):

Has anyone mentioned the [`DateTime.DayOfYear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofyear.aspx) property?

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2001, 12, 14);
            dynamic dayofyear = dt.DayOfYear;
            dynamic datofweek = dt.DayOfWeek;
```

Comment: means whenever you want you can convert it to anything else like string , int and datetime easily

Comment: Its just as easy to convert it with a static type, and it enforces typing rules.  There is no reason to use dynamic here.